# can't display model in gsp page

Tags: grails, groovy

So I've just started using Grails/Groovy for my senior capstone project and I'm having a bit of a rocky start. The issue I'm having is when I set up a mapping of my model in the controller I can loop through it and print it to the console but when I try and access it from the view I get  blank page.

The Domain class is simple:

```
package ot

class CrewDeskMapping {
    String crewDesk
    String desk
}
```

And the Bootstrap file that creates the test data:

```
...
new CrewDeskMapping(crewDesk:"North",desk:"MON1").save()
new CrewDeskMapping(crewDesk:"North",desk:"TWI1").save()
new CrewDeskMapping(crewDesk:"North",desk:"NWE1").save()
...
```

Here is my controller:

```
import ot.CrewDeskMapping;

class DashboardController {

def index() { 

    def desks = CrewDeskMapping.list()
    [desks:desks]
    for (d in desks) {
        System.out.println(d.desk);
    }
}
}
```

and the console output looks as it should:

```
MON1
TWI1
NWE1
CHI1
COL1
...
```

And the relevant part of my index.gsp

```
<body>
<g:each in="${desks}">
    <p>Title: ${it.crewDesk}</p>
    <p>Author: ${it.desk}</p>
</g:each>
</body>
```

The most perplexing part is if I try this same code but with a different Domain it works just fine. I've been at this problem for a couple days now with no avail so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def desks = CrewDeskMapping.list()
[desks:desks]
for (d in desks) { ...
```

does not return your `[desks: desks]`

Swap the `for` and the `[desks: ...]` or add a proper return statement at the end like this:

```
def index() {
    def desks = CrewDeskMapping.list()
    desks.each{ log.debug it.desk } // groovier debug print
    // must be last in the method like a regular return in java,
    // but groovy allows implicit return of the last statement
    /*return*/ [desks:desks]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't even remember reading anywhere that it had to be at the end!

Comment: For better code readability, I recommend using the `respond` method. See this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/respond.html

Comment: Or even more obvious and less esoteric - use the optional `return` keyword ;)